# Rejection sampling ineffectiveness in high dimensions

Tags: sampling, rejection-sampling, accept-reject

I guess I really have two questions.

First, iv'e seen quoted in a couple of places that the probability of accepting a given sample in a rejection sampling algorithm (sampling from a density $f$ with an envelope $g$) is $1/k$, where $k$ is the constant by which $g$ is multiplied to dominate $f$ (so $k=\sup_x \frac{f\left(x\right)}{g\left(x\right)}$)

What if $f$ is an unnormalized measure? Does this affect the probability of acceptance? It seems so.. but feels like it shouldn't

Second, in [these](https://sailinglab.github.io/pgm-spring-2019/notes/lecture-13/) lecture notes, it's stated as an example for the ineffectiveness of rejection sampling in high dimensions that taking two Gaussians of dimension $d$
$$f\left(x\right)=\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_{1}I_d\right)$$
$$g\left(x\right)=\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_{2}I_d\right)$$

with $\sigma_{1}\neq\sigma_{2}$ will cause the acceptance rate to plummet with increasing $d$. Specifically, it says that for $d=1,000$ the acceptance rate will be $\sim \frac{1}{20,000}$. Can someone point out the dependence on $d$ here?

Comment: See our posts on [the curse of dimensionality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=curse+dimensional*).  This is the simplest possible example: the relative (hyper)volumes described by these matrices scale as $(\sigma_1/\sigma_2)^d.$

Comment: @whuber I couldn't find a computation to this effect in the search page you suggested. To clarify, you mean the hypervolume of a Gaussian with $\sigma_1$ vs. the [scaled up version] dominating one with $\sigma_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...the probability of accepting a given sample in a rejection sampling
> algorithm (sampling from a density $f$ with an envelope $g$) is $1/k$,
> where $k$ is such that $$k\ge\sup_xf(x)/g(x)$$ Whenf $f$ is an
> unnormalized measure, does this affect the probability of acceptance?

The acceptance-rejection method **does not depend** on the normalising constants of $f$ and $g$ and can thus be operated with unnormalised versions $\tilde f$ and $\tilde g$, using the associated constant$$\tilde k\ge\sup_x\tilde f(x)/\tilde g(x)$$**This does not impact the efficiency of the algorithm in that the probability of acceptance remains equal to $1/k$** and not $1/\tilde k$. The reason for this invariance is that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P_{U\sim \mathcal U(0,1),X\sim g}\left(U\le \frac{\tilde f(X)}{\tilde k\tilde g(X)}\right) &=
\mathbb P_{U\sim \mathcal U(0,1),X\sim g}\left(U\le  \frac{f(x)}{k g(X)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{k}
\end{align}
The fundamental reason for this invariance is that one does not generate from $\tilde g$ but always from $g$: simulation [when possible] over-rides the missing constant.

> Can someone point out the dependence on $d$?

Take a simple case when $$f(\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^d f_0(x_i)$$ and
$$g(\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^d g_0(x_i)$$with
$$\sup_x \dfrac{f_0(x)}{g_0(x)}=k_0$$Then
$$\sup_\mathbf x \dfrac{f(\mathbf x)}{g(\mathbf x)}=k_0^d=k$$
explains why the acceptance probability decreases as a power of $d$.